# Different characterizations of Liouville numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, continued-fractions, liouville-numbers

Usually, Liouville numbers are defined as follows:
$x$ is Liouville if for ever $i\in\mathbb N$ there exist $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|x-\frac nm\right|<\frac1{m^i}.
\end{equation}
In their 1982 paper on almost-periodic Schrödinger operators, however, Avron and Simon use the following definition:
$x$ is Liouville if for ever $i\in\mathbb N$ there exist $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|x-\frac nm\right|<\frac1{i^m}.
\end{equation}
Do these sets of numbers agree? If yes, how can one show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a long-time misuse of terminology. The second definition is not of a Liouville number, it is much stronger. Liouville number is a number which can be approximated by rationals at any power rate. The second definition assumes that a number can be approximated at any exponential rate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...yet both sets are of measure 0 and dense $G_\delta$...
Why do Avron and Simon coin them Liouville numbers, then?

Comment: As I said, seems to be some old misuse of terminology. I was not able to  trace it to the origin, which may well be Avron and Simon's paper.

Comment: Ok thanks! I also couldnt find any other source for that (and obviously the monograph by Cycon, Froese, Kirsch and Simon). They need the second bound, though, to apply Gordon's theorem...